# 3D oblique projection view, how to change y-axis

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I want to have a 3D oblique projection view:
[image]

For this I use a code (just without axes) like this

```
angle = 30;
surf(x, -x*sind(angle)+y*cosd(angle),z)
axis off
view([90,50])
```

Another solution that works similarly (using coordinate transformation for objects, not for axes) is here [Oblique projection in Matlab mesh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25430770/oblique-projection-in-matlab-mesh) (it was indicated by **gnovice**):

[image]

But I need to properly display the axes, too. Is it possible to achieve axis properties (y-axis) to change the display of its direction (for example, using Java)?

Comment: The projection you're looking for is called an [oblique projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oblique_projection), and while there is no built-in way to do it in MATLAB, there is a user-submitted option provided by the answer in the linked duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to view your plot from a specific angle (as you describe), `view` is quite elegant, but your code does not do what you describe.

With `view([90,50])` you get Z- and Y-axes in the horizontal and vertical directions, not Z and X.

[image: <code>view([90,50])</code>]

What you want is `view([0,0])`.

[image: <code>view([0,0])</code>]

Though you cannot have your axes exactly as you show, but `view([0,0])` is close to (X-axis is not quite horizontal, but close to).

[image: <code>view([10,15])</code>]

Code used to demonstrate:

```
x=1:0.1:4;
y=1:0.1:4;
[X,Y]=meshgrid(x,y);
Z=sin(X).^2+cos(Y).^2;
surf(X,Y,Z);
xlabel('x')
ylabel('y')
zlabel('z')
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately, your answer does not fit to my question. In your examples, y- axis is vertical or x- axis is not horizontal. I need both: horizontal x-axis with non-vertical y-axis.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is changing `Projection` to `perspective` as documented at https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes-properties.html#prop_Projection, followed by using `view([0,0])`. For example, if you run

```
x = linspace(0,1);
y = linspace(0,1);
[xx,yy] = meshgrid(x,y);
zz = xx.^2 + yy.^2;
surf(xx,yy,zz)
xlabel('x')
ylabel('y')
zlabel('z')
ax = gca;
ax.Projection = 'perspective';
view([0,0])
```

you will get the following figure:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. But I do not need perspective (vanishing point(s)). I need a parallelepiped, as I have shown in the figure made by MS Word or generated by the code in my question.